# How to bring alert message if iPod have not moved for 60min?

Tags: objective-c-blocks, gyroscope, core-motion, motion, uiaccelerometer

My task is to bring an alert message if the device has not been moved for 60 minutes.. Not even single tilt

*Example:*

**i) To Bring Alert Message:**
          Let us consider iPod has been placed on table for 60 min.. it was not moved at all.. At end of 60min i have to bring alert message..

**ii) Don't Bring Alert Message:**
          if iPod has been moved some where or single tilt happen in-between that 60min.. then i don't want to bring alert message.
          If device is moving or tilt or shaking or rotating continuously then don't want to bring alert message.

Comment: Listening to accelerometer sensor updates may help.have you tried?